# How to write continuously in an array

Tags: c, arrays, binary, hex

Im making a calculator for binary/hexadecimal numbers where the user insert an 8 digits hexadecimal number and i need to convert it to binary and print it following by the operations. My problem is that after i read the hexadecimal number in an array and try to convert it and store it in another array, after i print it i get weird caracters(V<#■   jst]tt)

This is part of my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <float.h>
    #include <proyecto.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main () {
      char op,bin[31],hex[100],hex2[100];
      int sizeh,repeat1,repeat2,n,z,i;
        printf("Hexadecimal: ");
        scanf("%s",hex);
        convert(hex,bin,n);
```

convert function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <proyecto.h>
#include <string.h>
void convert(char hex[],char bin[],int n){
int i,b;
printf("\nEquivalent binary value: ");
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
switch(hex[i]){
case '0': scanf("0000",bin); break;
case '1': scanf("0001",bin); break;
case '2': scanf("0010",bin); break;
case '3': scanf("0011",bin); break;
case '4': scanf("0100",bin); break;
case '5': scanf("0101",bin); break;
case '6': scanf("0110",bin); break;
case '7': scanf("0111",bin); break;
case '8': scanf("1000",bin); break;
case '9': scanf("1001",bin); break;
case 'A': scanf("1010",bin); break;
case 'B': scanf("1011",bin); break;
case 'C': scanf("1100",bin); break;
case 'D': scanf("1101",bin); break;
case 'E': scanf("1110",bin); break;
case 'F': scanf("1111",bin); break;
case 'a': scanf("1010",bin); break;
case 'b': scanf("1011",bin); break;
case 'c': scanf("1100",bin); break;
case 'd': scanf("1101",bin); break;
case 'e': scanf("1110",bin); break;
case 'f': scanf("1111",bin); break;
default:  printf("\nInvalid hexadecimal digit %c ",hex[i]);
}
}
printf("%s",bin);
}
```

The point of the function is to write continously in the binary array the characters, so if i type AB the array will first insert 1010 and in the position 5 will keep writing 1011 but somehow i dont manage it to work

Comment: What do you think `scanf` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `scanf("0000",bin);` to `strcat(bin, "0000");` and so on.
Note that this method is cumbersome and `bin` must be large enough and initialized to the empty string, eg:

```
char bin[33] = "";
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you think the question was good enough to answer but not to upvote?

Comment: @user1717828: I just forgot to do it.  The lack of indentation is certainly a turn off ;-)